# Is a sum with two variables equal to two separate sums with one variable each?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Does $\sum_{i \in M, k \in S} f(i, k) = \sum_{i \in M} \sum_{k \in S} f(i, k)$ for all $f$?

Comment: Yes.  As long as there are only finitely many terms to sum you can do so in any order.

Comment: For a proof, see Terence Tao, *Analysis I* (2006), Lemma 7.1.13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I will assume everything is finite for the sake of simplicity, because I do not want to have to deal with convergence.

For a finite sum, the order of a sum does not matter, since you simply sum every elements of a same set. In particular, both sums you wrote are equal to $\sum_{c\in M\times S}f(c)$.
If you have infinite sums, the same is true under the right assumptions (e.g absolute convergence etc...), a first discussion about this can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence.